# iOS: Line between navigation top bar and other contents of UIviewController

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I create an app with Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1, I have a view controller with navigation bar, my view shows a line (separator) between the bar and other viewController's content.

I use following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

But nothing changed, for more details here's a screenshot: [image: This image of what I have]

What I can do to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

And if you want to apply this effect to the whole app (so that you don't need to write this code for every navigation controller) you can use:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```